# How to detect a non zero value in a binary file?

Tags: c#, xml, binary, arrays

I have a problem which has been torturing for many hours. I need to be able to find the first non-zero value in an array (taking into account that there might be zeroes afterwards).

So if:

```
A [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 48, 24, 0, 0, 18, 9, 9, 7, 8, 0];
```

How do I set a variable say, int origin; equal to 9, such that A [origin] = 16?

My actual problem is more complex than this but that's essentially a simplified version of what's got me stuck. I'm actually working with a bluetooth device that outputs sectors of 512 bytes, however each byte in that sector represents different things. So I have made a for loop to extract byte number 224 which is the one i'm interested in, then I made an array of the value 224 for each sector. Although all the other bytes in the sector contain data, this particular byte doesn't start transmitting until much later. Since I want to analyse the data I need to know in which sector it starts being useful. Hence, I have the question above. All this information is completely irrelevant to the question but i've provided it for background.

Furthermore, and if you really want to top yourself with an answer, i need to output the byte number 224 as "latitude", byte number 225 as "longuitude" and byte 226 as "elevation" (for a GPS) as an xml format. Any ideas as to how i would output my three byte arrays to xml format? I have read they must be in string form first but that's easy:

```
string [] Lat = new string [Sectors];
for (int i = 0, i < sectors; i++)
{
   Lat[i] = A[i].ToString();
}
```

In the end, I'd like this as a result.

```
<document>
    <point lat = "50.0" lon = "-60.5" ele = "605">
        <time> 16:54:08 </time>
    </point>
    <point .... etc
</document>
```

I hope I gave you enough information and I'd be helpful for ANY kind of help. cheers everyone! By the way, all the code should be in c# and I use visual c# 2010 express.

Comment: I'm confused - just read it as binary, either in entirety (if small) or via Stream.Read (if larger), and check for zeros... Maybe using an unsafe byte*/int* hack if you need to optimize. What is the problem, exactly?

Comment: Marc has your solution, however for your longitude and latitude issue, one byte is not enough information hold those values. I think you are interpreting the data format wrong. (For example -60.5 can not be represented by a byte (a byte can't do decimals or negatives) and 605 can be represented either (255 is the highest number you could have))

Comment: @Marc: I know, you are both right. I actually have 4 bytes for lat, lon, and elev. and they are actually float arrays. I used FileStream and BinaryReader to import the file as a byte array. then used: temp[0] = Trama[127]; temp[1] = Trama[126]; temp[2] = Trama[125]; temp[3] = Trama[124]; // reverse order.
     float p = BitConverter.ToSingle(temp, 0); to convert to a float. but i simplified the question because it's the concept that i don't understand. But you're right, i should have been clearer from the beginning. But thanks a lot!

Comment: @new if you are talking binary, I'd just use Stream (and I do; lots). I wouldn't use BinaryReader/BinaryWriter here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You state "array" in the question, which makes it easier:

```
int index = -1;    
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.Length ; i++)
{
    if(arr[i] != 0)
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now if index is non-negative it is the index of the first non-zero. The value is then arr[index].

If you need to read from a FileStream just loop over Read and repeat. There is a hack with unsafe code you can use to make it marginally faster if you need.

Comment: ok brilliant. How about the XML part, are there any c# modules to help me along? or do i have to make a for loop and write strings directely onto a txt file?

Comment: @new - `XmlSerializer` or `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` or `XmlWriter` - many options.

Comment: ok thanks. In the end i have used: TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);    Because the structure i´m using is pretty simple, (just position and time).   But i'm looking into those modules now for future projects.   Seriously though, thanks a million. I don't know what i would have done for this project without stackoverflow. It works a million times faster and better than the official microsoft site. You guys can take pride on that!    again, a million thanks!

Comment: @new that is enirely due to the strength of the community. But yes, it works well. On behalf of SE, thanks for your thanks!

Comment: @new btw - don't build XML by hand unless you have considered all the escaping/encoding concerns. I wouldn't write XML without a trusted writer, personally.